# Error Android Xamarin C#

Tags: android, c#, xamarin.forms

Queria saber si a alguien mas le ha pasado.
Una vez que compilo el proyecto correctamente(Visual studio 2015) y se genera la apk
Instalo la aplicacion en mi celular Android la abro y me sale el mensaje
"La aplicacion se ha interrumpido inesperadamente"
*La aplicacion tiene un boton nada mas.
Si alguien me ayuda a saber que puede estar mal :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin duda tienes que hacer un debug de tu app para determinar el problema, una de las causas más comunes son el uso de variables no instanciadas. De igual forma te recomiendo leer cómo crear un [mcve] para que tu pregunta tenga un mayor impacto y atención.

Comment: ¿Con que estas generando el emulador de Android?

Comment: *Si deseas desarrollar aplicaciones Android, el uso del LogCat es necesario, si no haces uso del LogCat puedes estar horas tratando de encontrar un problema que se puede corregir de una forma sencilla.* Que mensaje de error se muestra en el Log.

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice @Jorgesys, revisa este enlace: https://somostechies.com/qd-como-acceder-a-los-logs-y-trace-vsemulator/#.WNVIL-llC70 te permite acceder a los Logs y el trace del emulador de Visual Studio :D

Comment: ¿Lograste hacer que funcione?

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 0):

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Baja [Visual Studio Emulator para Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/es/vs/msft-android-emulator/)
2. Crea una nueva maquina virtual.
3. Inicia la maquina virtual.
4. Junto a la flecha verde cambia el dispositivo por el que tienes encendido.

La maquina virtual que tienes configurada es para **[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)** y da problemas con **Xamarin**.

**Nota:** Va a ser necesario que tengas Hyper-V habilitado para que todo funcione bien.